# How to get second largest value in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I want second largest value. I can get first largest by using 
max(field name) but how i can get 2nd largest.Is there any custom code.
I am new so any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

**I want it in SSRS**

Comment: It depends on where you want to put it (tablix or TextBox), you can select just the second biggest value in your dataset Query then you will have only one value to display

Comment: I want it in SSRS report function expression

Comment: Can you provide more detail where you want to display this value? Can you order your dataset query by this column or that is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` your field `DESC`, then limit the result set to 1 row, starting at the 2nd row:

```
SELECT field FROM TABLE ORDER BY field DESC LIMIT 1, 1;
```

(This is MySQL syntax, your engine may vary.)

Answer (score 0):

This is messy but It should work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    [column] 
FROM [table]
WHERE [column] <> 
    (
        Select top 1 
            [column] 
        from [table] 
        order by [column] DESC
    ) 
ORDER BY [column] DESC
```

If this is in a procedure and you dont care about doing 2 queries this looks a bit neater:

```
DECLARE @MAX INT
SELECT TOP 1 @MAX = MAX([COLUMN]) from [table] order by [COLUMN] desc
SELECT TOP 1 [COLUMN] FROM [TABLE] WHERE [COLUMN] <> @mAX order by [COLUMN] desc
```